# Update distinct rowcount in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
No     Name
1       A
1       A
1       A
1       A 
1       B
1       B
2       A
2       A
2       A
3       A
```

I need the result like this

```
   No     Name   Seq
    1       A     4
    1       A     4
    1       A     4
    1       A     4
    1       B     2 
    1       B     2
    2       A     3
    2       A     3
    2       A     3
    3       A     1
```

If `No` and `Name` are the same means update the count in the `seq` column.

I tried the following query

```
Select LEAD(Count(No),1) Over (PARTITION BY No,Name Order by No,Name) Seq
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Do you want an update or select?

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()` :

```
select no, name, count(*) over (partition by no, name) as seq
```

If you want to update the table then you can use *cte* :

```
with u_cte as (
     select no, name, count(*) over (partition by no, name) as seq
     from table t 
    )
update t
       set t.seq = u.seq  
from u_cte u inner join
     table t
     on t.no = u.no and t.name = u.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using `Count()` function and `inner join`.

```
create table MyTableA(Nos int, Name char(1))
insert into MyTableA values
(1       ,'A'),
(1       ,'A'),
(1       ,'A'),
(1       ,'A'), 
(1       ,'B'),
(1       ,'B'),
(2       ,'A'),
(2       ,'A'),
(2       ,'A'),
(3       ,'A')

SELECT MyTableA.*
    ,tblB.Seq
FROM myTableA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Nos
        ,Name
        ,Count(*) AS Seq
    FROM MyTableA
    GROUP BY Nos
        ,Name
    ) tblB ON MyTableA.Nos = tblB.Nos
    AND MyTableA.Name = tblB.Name
```

Live [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69f001d3c85e7d295a58ad363b7bff2f) with update statement.